# Can you change content in database via query

Tags: sql, database

I have a data base with a column named "URL" I want to change all the rows from http://site.com to www.site.com. I just want to remove the http:// and replace with www. in every row. Is that possible via a query or do i need to manually change them all?

Comment: You should specify the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the DBMS you're using, but I would think this sort of solution would work - most anything should have equivalent functions/operators (the below is Oracle SQL):

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET url = CONCAT( 'www.', SUBSTR(url, 8, LENGTH(url) - 7) )
 WHERE url LIKE 'http://%'
```

Comment: why not use `REPLACE` @CsharpBeginner ?

Comment: On the off-chance that the URL contains a second `http://` string (yes, very unlikely but not impossible), `REPLACE()` would replace that one as well -- at least in Oracle and SQL Server. YMMV.

Comment: Is case sensitivity going to be an issue (any urls with HTTP)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? Can you elaborate more on your question?

```
UPDATE tableName
SET `URL` = 'www.site.com'
WHERE `URL` = 'http://site.com'
```

how about using `REPLACE`?

```
UPDATE tableName
SET `URL` = REPLACE(LOWER(`URL`), 'http://','www')
```

I added `LOWER()` function since `REPLACE()` is case sensitive.

Comment: All of the urls are different though. I have 8000 urls in the database